# What would cause my request timer to report such long request execution times?

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

I am using a modified version of the code [here](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/02/httpmodule-for-timing-requests.aspx).  The difference is that I log it to a database and only if it is longer that 5000ms.  The results have me worried.  Several pages will occasionally log an execution time of minutes.  Never will they consistently under perform, but according to log table, it is happening often enough that I need to get to the bottom of it.

So I'm throwing it out here to see what kind of ideas the community has.  Perhaps it's due to app restarts?  recompiles?  Maybe some subtle flaw in the httpmodule that would cause it to misreport the time?

Comment: are the performance problems come in bulks or are they isolated?

Comment: I'd consider them spread out.  ~12 per hour in some cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run your application through a profiler to see which methods are taking up the most processing time.

Comment: There are free trials of Red Gate's ANTS profiler and jetBrains' dotTrace profiler. On the freeware side, EQUATEC Profiler is quite good. I've used it once or twice and haven't found any problems with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try keeping a close watch on the locks on your database, it could be a database locking issue, as that has happened to me and caused very similar symptoms.

Answer (score 0):

Check the system event log to see if there are any correlated events.  Looking for service restarts or service crashes, etc.

You're going to need to log more information until you can pinpoint the issue.  Hopefully its only happening on a particular page so you can isolate it that way...  Don't fall into the trap of trying to fix the problem before you really understand it.